# how to add fonts path in default_head_blocks.xml file magento 2 custom theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

> Actually i am trying to add fonts path in default_head_blocks.xml file
>   magento 2 custom theme.
>
> I added fonts files in app/design/vendor/theme/web/fonts. I am trying to
>   get this path.

Answer (score 0):

You can add path of custom fonts in `_typography.less` of your custom theme which located at `app/design/vendor/theme/web/source/_typography.less` file like below:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto.woff2') format('woff2'),
   url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto.woff') format('woff');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;    
}
```

**Note:** Add your font files in `app/design/vendor/theme/web/fonts` directory.

And you can assign this font in default font variable like below:

```
@font-family-name__base: 'Roboto';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this steps from the official DevDocs
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css

Plus you also need to do what Dipesh Rangani said on the previous answer. 
Both steps are needed.